# How can I know the scope of process code in the memory through PE file?

Tags: c

Can I get the scope of process code in the memory through PE file or someway?

If I have a process like this

example.exe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func()
{
  char str[10];

  strcpy( str, "iambuffer\n" );

  printf( "%s", str );
} // func()

int main()
{
  func();

  return 0;
} // main()
```

I can use `Ollydgb` to know that the scope of example.exe in the memory, and my question is how can I know these information without using Ollydgb?

thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean with "scope of process code in the memory"?

Comment: Besides that, strcpy() will write beyond the end of str in your example.

Comment: just like I can use Ollydgb to get the process scope like 0x00401270 ~0x00401382

Comment: Would you explain the final goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have a pointer to the PE (casted from an `HMODULE`), you can get the processes virtualized code size like so (not, it'll always be a multiple of the page size):

```
inline ULONG_PTR GetModuleSize(HMODULE hModule)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pDOSHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)hModule;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pNTHeaders =(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)((BYTE*)pDOSHeader + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew);
    return pNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
}
```

So of course the range will become `(ULONG_PTR)hModule` to `(ULONG_PTR)hModule + GetModuleSize(hModule)`

One can enumerate the various sections if you want a finer grained memory mapping. See the [Win32 PE reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx). If you want the stack bounds, you can get those from the TIB.
(funnily enough I also made this function cause I wanted that feature of olly's).

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is a `.map` file. Its the one the linker generates and contains all symbol addresses, and the program layout too. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is one specific example if you are using Visual Studio.

Check for the `.map` or a similar extension file in your build environment and it'll be in text format most of the times, so you can analyse it easily.